# the proper method for making a DB connection available across many python modules

Tags: python, mysql

I want to make a single database object available across many python modules.

For a *related* example, I create globl.py:

```
DOCS_ROOT="c:\docs" ## as an example
SOLR_BASE="http://localhost:8636/solr/"
```

Any other module which needs it can do a

```
from globl import DOCS_ROOT
```

Now this example aside, I want to do **the same thing with database connection objects, share them across many modules**.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost"...)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I tried this on the interpreter:

```
from globl import cursor
```

and it seems to work. But I suspect that this will **cause the same module to be executed each time one imports** from it. So is this the proper way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You suspect wrongly. The code will only be executed once - subsequent imports just refer to the module via `sys.modules`, and don't re-run it.

(Note that this is the case as long as you always use the same path to import the module - if you do `from globl import cursor` in one place, and `from my.fullyqualified.project.global import cursor` in another, you probably will find the code is re-executed.)

**Edit to add** as S.Lott says in the comment, this is a perfectly good way to handle a global object.

Comment: What about "is this the proper way?"  I think that you should point out that a module global like this works out pretty well in the long run.

Answer (score 50):

Even if the import doesn't run the code multiple times, this is definitely not the correct way.

You should instead hide the process of obtaining a connection or cursor behind a function. You can then implement this function using either a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or [Object Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) design pattern.

So it would be something like this:

**db.py:**

```
_connection = None

def get_connection():
    global _connection
    if not _connection:
        _connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost"...)
    return _connection

# List of stuff accessible to importers of this module. Just in case
__all__ = [ 'getConnection' ]

## Edit: actually you can still refer to db._connection
##         if you know that's the name of the variable.
## It's just left out from enumeration if you inspect the module
```

**someothermodule.py:**

```
import db
conn = db.get_connection() # This will always return the same object
```

By the way, depending on what you are doing, it may not be so much of a good idea to share
your connection object rather than create a new one every time you need one.

But, that's why you'd want to write a `get_connection()` method, to abstract from these issues in the rest of your code.

Comment: Great answer, this too. I would have chosen this one as this is teaches something new.

Comment: If i run this code I get UnboundLocalError: local variable '_connection' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Jim That's true. It was a rushed example. I've added a line with `global _connection`.

Comment: using `__all__` also has the nice feature of representing the things that'll be imported into your namespace using `import *`. not that you should ever use `import *` if you can help it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think Daniel already answered the question, while I'd like to add few comments about the cursor object you want to share.

It is generally not a good idea to share the cursor object that way. Certainly it depends on what your program is, but as a general solution I'd recommend you to hide this cursor object behind a "factory" producing cursors. Basically you can create a method `cursor()` or `get_cursor()` instead of making the cursor a global variable. The major benefit (but not the only one) - **you can hide a more complex logic behind this "factory"** - pooling, automatic re-connection in case the connection is dropped, etc. Even if you don't need it right away - it will be very easy to add it later if you start using this approach now, and while for now you can keep this function implementation as simple as `return _cursor`.

And yes, still, the module itself will be imported once only.

Comment: I will refer this in future. Its a fine way of making complex stuff behind a simple interface.