# How to make database cursor global?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have connection function to Mysql database:

```
def connectDB():
    conn = mysql.connector.Connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='grabber')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM local")
    return cursor
```

So, I want to use `cursor` in others methods inside my code list, therefore I need this as global variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean just use: `from global import cursor`?

Comment: I mean that question is already have been asked. You need to figure out what solution best suits you.

Comment: There is not solution there

Comment: Refer to the [second answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6830296/216074).

Comment: The second solution is not way, I tried